Unknown `InternetAddress` calls in log of the Dart Network Tool
While debugging some REST calls I stumbled upon a lot of get calls of this type:

Can anyone explain to me what the entries with the form
GET InternetAddress(ipAddressString, IPv4) Type ws mean and where the origin of that could be because I know of none of our own code that would do that and the IP address can't be looked up and I have no idea what sort of target this could be.
Interestingly these lines only recently in the network view but I don't know if this is because of new features in the network view or because we added some package that does these calls.

The "ws" part are a known bug (reported by me 3 years ago...): https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3033
It is most likely TCP sockets themself you are seeing where the HTTP/HTTPS traffic are going though. If you are not reusing your HttpClient instance, it will not try reuse existing connections which can give this pattern you are seeing where you are seeing new sockets getting created to the same endpoint.

Thanks! actually we do reuse just one HttpClient for all our calls.

Ok, might be worth taking a look at the settings then on your HttpClient. Could also be your server implementation that kills the raw socket itself after request are handled.

I'm trying to better understand exactly that. It seems that some calls reuse the same client because there is no connection time and then the next already has a log connection time. idleTimeout is 15 seconds which should be enough

Ah yeah if idleTimeout are set to 15 seconds, it makes sense that the times we see in your screenshot are showing the connection got closed after at least 15 seconds. So connections are getting reused. It is just that you have a pause in new connections for at least 15 seconds sometimes which makes them close.
